# i want a function that toggles between displaying hidden divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, display, hidden

```
<div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="1">1</div>
    <div class="1">2</div>
    <div class="1">3</div>
    <div class="1">4</div>
    <div class="1">5</div>
<div>
  <button class="switch">1</button>
  <button class="switch">2</button>
  <button class="switch">3</button>
  <button class="switch">4</button>
  <button class="switch">5</button>
</div>
```

Please I need to be able to display one div at a time when I click on its corressponding button

Comment: What is your question? Where in the process of writing your code are you stuck? Note that [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), [CSS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Reference), [HTML docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Reference), [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript), [CSS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS), and [HTML tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/HTML) are freely available.

Comment: please i want when i click button 2 the div 2 alone should display, likewise other buttons

Comment: Button action is normally linked to javascript, I suggest learning that before you continue with what you are trying to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to control the style with javascript then you can use this slightly modified code:

```
<div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="display" id="1">1</div>
    <div class="display" id="2">2</div>
    <div class="display" id="3">3</div>
    <div class="display" id="4">4</div>
    <div class="display" id="5">5</div>
</div>
<button class="switch">1</button>
<button class="switch">2</button>
<button class="switch">3</button>
<button class="switch">4</button>
<button class="switch">5</button>
<script>
    const checklist = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
    function hideAll(){
        for (var item of checklist){
            document.getElementById(item).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function show(id){
        hideAll();
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "initial";
    }
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
        let id = checklist[i];
        divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){show(id)});
    }
</script>
```